Python typing: accept kwargs only with some class' methods
Is it possible to somehow extract some class' methods type and use them in kwargs?
Example of what I want:
class A:
    prop: int = 10

    def foo(self):
        pass

    def bar(self):
        pass

def fun[T](**kwargs: Idk[T]):
    pass

fun[A](foo=lambda: 123) # this is correct
fun[A](prop=200) # this is not
fun[A](smth=lambda: 123) # this is not

Equivalent in TypeScript, which works:
class A {
    prop: number = 100;

    foo() {}

    bar() {}
}

type OnlyMethods<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Function ? K : never]: T[K];
};

function fun<T>(arg: Partial<OnlyMethods<T>>) {}

fun<A>({
    bar() {}, // this works
});

fun<A>({
    prop: 200, // error
});

fun<A>({
    smth() {}, // error
});


I don't think this is a thing you can do in Python's typing system.  If you wanted to statically verify that a set of function args matched a set of class methods you might be able to put something together with Protocol...?

The specific thing you're asking for is not achievable. But there may be alterative approaches (eg. partial types dicts, protocols, unions of function definitions, or even subclassing). But without a specific example of the end result you are trying to achieve, it is hard to make any recommendations.

This is not currently possible.
To specify a specific shape for **kwargs, the only way is to use an Unpacked TypedDict. A TypedDict, however, can only ever be defined using class D(TypedDict)/D = TypedDict('D', ...), in which all keys must be hardcoded.
You would be better off sticking with established patterns/conventions and staying away from magic if static typing is your goal.
